# start функции anim.js через jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

здраствуйте у меня проблема

```
var func = anime({
  tergets:".target",
  translateY:100,
  autostart:false
});
```

```
document.querySelector(".button").onclick = func.restart; // запускает функцию
```

как также сделать но на jquery

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  func.restart;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector(".button").onclick = func.restart;`

Здесь в объекте первого HTML-элемента с классом ".button", в свойстве onclick записывается **ссылка** на функцию, которую должен вызвать клик. В большинстве случаев, его безопасно можно заменить на:

```
document.querySelector(".button").onclick = function(){
  func.restart();
};
```

Где onclick ссылается на функцию, которая при вызове - сама будет **вызывать** функцию `func.restart`

Соответственно, в jQuery это выглядит так:

```
$(".button").on('click', func.restart);

// Или

$(".button").on('click', function(){
  func.restart();
});
```